# Twig Swiftmailer without Symfony

Tags: php, twig, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use Standalone Twig to send emails with Swiftmailer.  I'm following for the [instructions](https://github.com/wemakecustom/swiftmailer-twig-bundle) at the "With a pure Swiftmailer/Twig" section.

This is my code:

```
require_once('/var/www/folder/includes/vendor/autoload.php');

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array('/var/www/templates/utilities/test'));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/var/www/templates/cached',
    'auto_reload' => true, // set to false to improve performance (Note: You have to clear the cache manually whenever a template is changed)
    'debug' => true,
    'use_strict_variables' => false,
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());



$swiftMailerTemplateHelper = new \WMC\SwiftmailerTwigBundle\TwigSwiftHelper($twig, '/var/www/templates/utilities/test');
// I'm not exactly sure what the value for the second parameter is supposed to be.
//The instructions referenced just list a variable called $web_directory.
//I'm assuming they just mean a path to where the templates are stored.

echo "hello world";
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'WMC\SwiftmailerTwigBundle\TwigSwiftHelper' not found in
>   /var/www/apps_mymea/utilities/test/email.php on line 16

Answer (score 1):

The namespace in the referenced documentation is incorrect.

The correct syntax is:

```
$swiftMailerTemplateHelper = new \WMC\SwiftmailerTwigBundle\Mailer\TwigSwiftHelper($twig, '/var/www/templates/utilities/test');
//It was missing the \Mailer\ in the class path.
```